# IIS 500 error when connecting to Access database via ODBC on Windows 10

Tags: php, ms-access, iis, odbc

I upgraded to from Windows 8.1 (64 bit) to Windows 10 (64 bit).  I run an IIS-10 server, with PHP, which does an ODBC connect to a MS-Access database.  I'm running the 32 bit version of Access 2016.  I have installed the Access/Jet database driver.

Using the 32 bit ODBC Data Source Administrator I created a DSN named "TFD_Local" which connects to a .accdb database on the server.

The PHP script which runs on IIS execute the following

```
 $odbc = odbc_connect('TFD_Local', '', '') or reportError("Connect error: " . odbc_errormsg() . " " . odbc_error());
```

and I get an:

```
HTTP Error 500.0 - Internal Server Error
C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\v5.4\php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly
```

I suspect that this has something to do with a 32/64 bit incompatibility as this runs OK on a 32 bit machine running the same software.  This used to run on my Win 8.1 64 bit system.  Note that things like phpinfo run just fine.  What needs to be done to keep this from generating the 500 error?

Comment: Note that I have tried "Enable 32-bit applications" in the default application pool, but the DefaultAppPool stops when I do that.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question:

I deleted the DSN which had been created by going through the Administrative Tools/ODBC Data Sources (32 Bit) and then ran  C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe and recreated it.  I don't know what the difference is, but this worked.

Comment: the sysWow is where 32 bit programs reside in x64 versions of  windows. (seems strange, since system32 is where x64 bit code useally resides!) The  ODBC manager when launched from  control panel launches the x64 bit version of ODBC manager by default. So to launch the x32 manager, then the one you point out in syswow is the correct version to run for x32 drivers. This likely suggests you are running the x32 bit version of IIS.

Comment: I have both the 32 bit and 64 bit ODBC managers in my Administrative Tools, but the one that is in C:\Windows\SysWOW64\odbcad32.exe has a slightly different interface than the one in Admin tools.  Like I said, I don't know what the difference is, but the one in SysWow64 works and the other one doesn't.

Comment: The syswow one is for x32 bit programs (so that is the correct version). You have to "match" the bit size of the drivers to the version of Access (Access has both a x32 version, and a x64 version - and I suppose it is worth pointing out that both versions cannot be installed at the same time). If you ever jump to the x64 bit version of IIS, then you have to start using the other ODBC  manager and ALSO install the x64 bit version of Access. In fact, it is MORE common to use x64 version of IIS - so you likely hit this issue in the future.

Comment: I believe that I am running the 64 bit version of IIS.  When I look in the task manager, I see w3wp.exe (IIS worker process) running and it's 64 bit.  The 64 bit ODBC manager shows the 32 bit data sources, but says that they must be managed from the 32 ODBC manager.